# vb.net datadrig view get each cell value

Tags: vb.net

hello i'm trying to get the first value of a datagrid cell value but it keeps looping trough and returns the last value. here is the code:

```
Dim cell As DataGridViewCell
    txtoccupier.Text = ""
    Try
        For Each cell In dgvREcord.CurrentRow.Cells()
            txtoccupier.Text = cell.Value.ToString
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Exit Try
    End Try
```

record eample:

```
id  name  email
--  ----  -----
1   test  test@test.com
```

it returns only test@test.com but i want to get only the id which is 1

thanks for your help

Comment: Hi, please edit you question so that the code gets formatted so that we can read it easier. Use the code button (5 from the left) or put 4 spaces in front of each line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looping over all of the cells in each row updating `txtoccupier.Text` each time. This will leave it holding the value of the last cell.

If you know you only want the value of the first cell don't loop, just access that cell's value directly:

```
txtoccupier.Text = dgvREcord.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString()
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're looping through all the cells in the row, skip the loop and just do `txtoccupier.Text = dgvREcord.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString()`